# Migration from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, software-recommendations, oracle-dbms

I am new to databases.

Is it possible to migrate from Oracle database to Postgres?

If yes, do you know any tested solutions?

Comment: There does not appear to be a GIS component to this pure DBMS question.

Comment: We migrated content from an Oracle database (>100 schema; >1000 tables, many with millions of rows) to Postgres using the (hacky!) approach at: https://github.com/MIT-LCP/oracle-to-postgres.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libogr can read and write both Oracle and PostGIS. Use the ogr2ogr utility to convert your data.

- https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs
- https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Works well enough for us.

Comment: Is it working regardless to database size?

Comment: I'm certain you can break it. Our main vector database has ~40M records in its largest table and a size of ~260GB.